# Odd moment and the characteristic function of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable and $\phi_X(t)$ be its characteristic function. Let $n$ be a positive even integer. If $\phi_X(t)$ is $n$-times differentiable, then the $n$-th moment of $X$ exists and equals $\phi^{(n)}_X(0)$. However, if $n$ is odd, there is no gaurantee that the $n$-th moment exists or equals to $\phi^{(n)}_X(0)$. I have read the proof of the former statement but cannot catch what causes problems for the odd moments. If there is some examples, it would be helpful. Would you provide some examples of the latter case? What I can found in textbooks are examples where $\phi_X$ is infinite times differentiable.

Comment: The classical (counter)example goes back to [Zygmund](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177730443)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chung's book has the following example in the exercises: let $X$ be a random variable taking the value $n$ with probability $C\frac 1 {n^{2}\log\,|n| }$ for $n=\pm 3,\pm 4,...$ where $C$ is chosen such that these probabilities add up to $1$. It is trivial to check that $E|X|=\infty$. However $\phi_X(t)=\sum_{|n| \geq 3} e^{int}C\frac 1 {n^{2}\log\,|n| }$. This series converges uniformly. If you differentiate this series term by term you get another uniformly convergent series. This requires the following theorem from the theory of Fourier series: $\sum a_n \sin(nx)$ converges uniformly if $a_n$ decreases to $0$ and $na_n \to 0$. We now use the basic fact from Calculus which says that if $\sum f_n$ and  $\sum f_n'$ are both uniformly convergent with each $f_n$ continuously differentiable then $\sum f_n$ is continuously differentiable. Hence  the characteristic function of $X$ is differentiable but the mean of $X$ is $\infty$.

Comment: Uniform convergence of $F(t) = \sum f_n(t)$ and $\sum f_n'(t)$ ensures $F'(0) = \sum f_n'(0)$. Is this right? Then I'm confused because $\sum f_n'(0) = EX = \infty$ by definition. If $F$ is differentiable at $0$, $F'(0)$ cannot diverge. This looks like a contradiction.

Comment: $\sum f_n'(0)$ is not $EX$. That is whole point of the example. You cannot relate the first derivative of the characteristic function and the first moment.

Comment: Uniform converences of $F(t) = \sum f_n(t)$ and $\sum f'_n(t)$ ensures $F'(0) = \sum f_n'(0)$. However $\sum f_n'(0) = \sum i n e^{i 0 n} P(n) = i \sum n P(n) = i EX$. I cannot see which equality is broken here.

Comment: Your argument requires absolute convergence of the series. We have uniform convergence but not absolute convergence.

Comment: As far as I know uniform convergence ensures it. For example, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformConvergence.html).

Comment: If $f_n(x)=(-1)^{n} /n$ the $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly but not absolutely.

Comment: Would you elaborate about the absolute convergence please? Which part of my argument requires it?

Comment: I came to realize that the "existence" of the $k$-th moment means absolute integrability of $X^k$. I understand the example now. Thanks.